# Integral Question - $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integral Question - $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x}}\,\mathrm dx$.
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x-1)}}\,\mathrm dx =\int \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt x} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

This is the right way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no constants $A,B$ such that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x-1)}}=\frac{A}{\sqrt x} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Comment: @Ofir : No.  $\sqrt{CD} \neq \sqrt{C} + \sqrt{D}$.  Complete the square inside the square root.

Comment: Yes, I understand that after lab told me, thanks

Comment: Concise anti derivative valid for all domain $$ \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x}} dx=\tanh^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x}}{x-\frac12} $$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) is for rational fraction only.

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-x}}=\int\frac{2dx}{\sqrt{4x^2-4x}}=\int\frac{2dx}{\sqrt{(2x-1)^2-1^2}}$$

Now, put $2x-1=\sec\theta$

**EDIT**: completing as requested

So,$2dx=\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$

$$\text{So,}\int\frac{2dx}{\sqrt{(2x-1)^2-1^2}}=\int \frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{\tan\theta}=\int \sec\theta d\theta =\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C $$ (where $C$ is an arbitrary constant of indefinite integral  )

$$=\ln\left|2x-1+\sqrt{(2x-1)^2-1}\right|+C=\ln\left|2x-1+2\sqrt{x^2-x}\right|+C$$

---

Alternatively,using
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-a^2}}=\ln\left|y+\sqrt{y^2-a^2}\right|+C$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-x}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\left(\frac12\right)^2}}$$
$$=\ln\left|x-\frac12+\sqrt{x^2-x}\right|+C=\ln\left|2x-1+2\sqrt{x^2-x}\right|+C-\ln2=\ln\left|2x-1+2\sqrt{x^2-x}\right|+C'$$ where $C'=C-\ln2$ another arbitrary constant

Comment: ok thanks, got it!

Comment: @OfirAttia, can $1$ be equal to $A\sqrt{x-1}+B\sqrt x?$

Comment: no, I see it right now. thanks

Comment: I can put outside the intergral 1/2? because the 2dx?

Comment: By the way, I dont need to add 2 right? I can leave it as is

Comment: This is what I get in the end : $\displaystyle{\sqrt{arctg(2x-1)}}\,\mathrm +  C$ or without the sqrt?

Comment: @OfirAttia, did you $2x-1=\sec\theta?$

Comment: Sorry I dont use sec and my teacher too.

Comment: and what about the square root on the right ?

Comment: @OfirAttia, sorry I missed that . $$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-x}}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2- \left(\frac12\right)^2}}$$  for $$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-a^2}}=\ln|y+\sqrt{y^2-a^2}|+C$$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8559/discussion-between-ofir-attia-and-lab-bhattacharjee)

Comment: if it was $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$. so I can pull out minus and say that is the same but with minus before?

Comment: @OfirAttia,$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac12\right)^2-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2}}$ Use $$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}=\arcsin \frac ya$$